# The Inverse Trigonometric Functions

Tags: trigonometry

I know that if $y=\sin x$ then $\arcsin y=x$; that is, $\arcsin$ is used for the inverse and $\arcsin$ is not a function if we don't restrict the domain of $y=\sin x$ but I don"t get that what is the meaning of arc in "$\arcsin$" because $\arcsin$ just gives us measures of angles $x$?

Comment: One way to see it is that we always denote an angle inside a polygon by drawing an arc between edges.

Answer (score 5):

The "arc" refers to an arc of a unit circle.  Thus in the following picture, $\arcsin(y)$ is the length of the blue arc.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Robert.